# New Map Scheme of Bing Maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I use New Map Scheme of Bing Maps in my  Windows Phone Application

as you can see here:
http://pocketnow.com/phones/bing-maps-on-windows-phone-7-is-using-new-map-scheme

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the appropriate MapTileSource but I don't think it's publicly available.